# gRPC client streaming with fast sender and slow receiver

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have a gRPC server with a client streaming endpoint to allow file uploads in small chunks. I'm trying to understand what will happen if a client invokes `onNext()` asynchronously with many messages on the stream much faster than the server can process them.

I implemented a Java client that invokes `onNext()` 100 times on the same stream over a few seconds, while the server is much slower to process the chunks. I understand the messages are being buffered by gRPC on the client side, and are not sent over the wire to the server until it is ready to receive them. After about 50-60 messages have been sent, I get `Shutting down gRPC server...` on the client and the call fails.

I have successfully implemented manual flow control on the client side to prevent sending too many messages in advance, but my question is whether this is necessary. Is this type of failure generally what happens to gRPC clients when they send streaming messages quicker than the server can handle them? Must every client explicitly implement manual flow control?

Additional question:

In my implementation, once the client started sending messages on the stream, the server processed them one by one (each `onNext()` call on the server only started once the previous  call ended). Is that always the case by design? Or does gRPC allow processing multiple messages on the same stream concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this type of failure generally what happens to gRPC clients when they send streaming messages quicker than the server can handle them? Must every client explicitly implement manual flow control?

No, please check out the [READMDE for the manual-flow example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/manualflowcontrol/README.md#outgoing-flow-control) which has this:

"By default, gRPC will handle dealing with flow control."

...

"The underlying layer (such as Netty) will make the write wait when there is no space to write the next message. This causes the request stream to go into a not ready state and the outgoing onNext method invocation waits."

> Is that always the case by design? Or does gRPC allow processing multiple messages on the same stream concurrently?

On the server side you provide a `StreamObserver` for your incoming request stream and gRPC will call `onNext` only sequentially from a single thread. However, in your `onNext` implementation you can use another thread (executor etc) to do the work (provided you take care of all the synchronization requirements for your application) and return immediately from `onNext` which allows gRPC to deliver the next request message by calling `onNext` again.

Hope that answers your questions.